# Broken URL, that was insertet per Lookup

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, html, url, images

Hello I have the following Problem:
I am using AMPScript in order to retrieve a picture, saved as an URL link in a data extension. However, some of the URLs are broken (unknown reason) and i want to create a fallback - best case no picture at all. But somehow the oneerror is not working. Do you have any idea how to proceed in this situation?

```
<table align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" width="100%">
             
              <tr>
               <td align="center" style="padding: 0px 30px 0px 30px;" width="100%">
                <img alt="" data-assetid="256122" height="200"  src="%%ProjektBild%%" onerror="if (this.src != '../error.png') this.src = '../error.png';" style="display: block; padding: 0px; text-align: center; height: 200px; width: 250px; 
border-width: 0px; border-color: transparent; 
border-style: solid;" width="250"><br>
                &nbsp;</td></tr></table>
```

Thank you in advance!

Kind regards,
Magi

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Are you placing this code in an email? In that case, javascript will not work.

Comment: @LukasLunow yes, i am placing it in the email. Do you have an idea how to process in this case?

Answer (score 0):

So i found a solution to the problem, including AMPScript:

```
<td>
    %%[ SET @link = AttributeValue("Bild") SET @picture = httpget(@link,true,1,@status) IF @status == 0 THEN ]%%
    <table align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td align="center" style="padding: 0px 30px 0px 30px;" width="100%">
                <img alt="" height="200" src="%%Bild%%" style="display: block; padding: 0px; text-align: center; height: 200px; width: 250px; border-width: 0px; border-color: transparent; border-style: solid;" width="250">
                <br>&nbsp;
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    %%[ENDIF]%%
</td>
```

I hope this might be helpful to someone!